# What the difference with Angular code

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm a little confused about this way of getting data from a component in Angular. Why or when should I use the public and get keywords, and is it even needed?

```
public get data$(): Observable<any> {  
    return this._data$;
}
```

In most examples I've seen it would be like this,

```
getData(){ 
    return this._data;
}
```

Also does the `$` have any special meaning?
I tried to google this, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: You're comparing TypeScript code in the first example to vanilla javascript in the second.

Comment: You use the public keyword if you want to expose your methods and variables. If you don't get this idea, I think starting right away in Angular is not a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getting data from a component in Angular.

This has nothing to do with Angular or components. It's just TypeScript.

1. You use the `public` keyword to make a method [public](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers).
2. You use the `get` keyword to write a [getter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors).

Both concepts are described well in the TypeScript docs, which you should run through.

The `$` is merely a naming convention often used for the names of variables which hold streams (observables).

The code fragment you give is perfectly valid TypeScript, since after all TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript.

```
getData(){ 
    return this._data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think $ is anything special than what angular makes it like for terms like $scope $watch this are term created in the angular library and data is normally stored in variables like $scope.data mainly because of the $scope variable can interact with the DOM view ,hope this clears u rather than confuses u

Comment: You're confusing the `$` as used in AngularJS with the `$` typically used as a naming convention to refer to streams (observables).